# Puma failing to run on Rails 5 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I'm trying to run my rails 5 site on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and everything seems to be working, except Puma keeps shutting down.

The logs are below. I've tried googling the error, but just get unrelated solutions to different problems. I'm assuming I have something wrong in my puma config file, but can't figure out what I need to change. Right now I just have the standard `puma.rb` file.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2018/08/08 19:19:31 [warn] 3023#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/08/08 19:20:34 [crit] 3027#0: *4 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.6.124, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "18.188.190.176"
2018/08/08 21:12:16 [warn] 2967#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/08/08 22:02:02 [warn] 5848#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/08/08 22:02:02 [warn] 5858#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored



-------------------------------------
/var/log/puma/puma.log
-------------------------------------
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 19:21:42 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 19:21:42 +0000 ===
[17439] - Worker 0 (pid: 17442) booted, phase: 0
[17439] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:12:05 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:12:05 +0000 ===
[2406] - Worker 0 (pid: 2459) booted, phase: 0
[2406] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `getwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `block in pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:70:in `pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/env.rb:43:in `block in report'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/env.rb:42:in `each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/env.rb:42:in `report'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:96:in `request_issue_report_for'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:46:in `log_error'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:126:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:12:55 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:12:55 +0000 ===
[3420] - Worker 0 (pid: 3423) booted, phase: 0
[3420] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `getwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `block in pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:70:in `pwd'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/env.rb:43:in `block in report'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/env.rb:42:in `each'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/env.rb:42:in `report'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:96:in `request_issue_report_for'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:46:in `log_error'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:126:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:56:20 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:56:20 +0000 ===
[5379] - Worker 0 (pid: 5382) booted, phase: 0
[5379] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:58:45 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-08 21:58:45 +0000 ===
[5532] - Worker 0 (pid: 5535) booted, phase: 0
[5532] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:36:36 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:36:36 +0000 ===
[11544] - Worker 0 (pid: 11547) booted, phase: 0
[11544] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:38:14 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:38:14 +0000 ===
[11706] - Worker 0 (pid: 11709) booted, phase: 0
[11706] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:43:55 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:43:55 +0000 ===
[12305] - Worker 0 (pid: 12308) booted, phase: 0
[12305] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:47:12 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2018-08-09 00:47:12 +0000 ===
[12506] - Worker 0 (pid: 12509) booted, phase: 0
```

Edit: My puma config file

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup
bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
# End AWS setup

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked webserver processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Comment: can u post puma.rb file also?

Comment: @7urkm3n yep. Just added it.

Comment: do u have an extensions ? also why do u use bind and pidfile ?

Comment: Just throwing mud at the wall. I’ve since removed those two lines. No extensions. The only thing I’ve added is the Postgres installer.